# Php PDO, Insert a changable varible

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

TEST WEBSITE: csgodice.co.uk

I've been looking into PDO, but it confuses me, i am only 14 and im not that knowledge about mysql in php all i know is to use PDO and some parts of databases, i was wondering how i would insert a changable value, such as balance, here is my information i want to insert into my table as rows

```
$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (64ID, BALANCE, AMOUNTBET)          VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $64id, $balance, $amountbet );

// set parameters and execute
$_64id = "$steamprofile['steamid']";
$balance = "";
$amountbet = "";

$stmt->execute();
```

I Have connected to my mysql so all that is done, all i really need to know is how to insert rows? i know there is documentation about it but the topics on there differ to what i am trying to do?

Comment: Variables name like `$64id` are not vaild. A variable name must start with a letter or the underscore character. A variable name cannot start with a number.

Comment: Also it balance and amountbet update, how would this update?

Comment: Ok thanks i will change it now :)

Comment: You can update those values in many different ways before you insert to the database.

Comment: To update the database record use `on duplicate update`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: Also how would i get the value of the balance in there account, its mearly just a html element right now displaying the value of 0.00

Comment: This question is going a lot of different ways http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Its all on the question though, im sorry i'll focus on one thing which is how would i insert a value that can update at anytime.

Comment: Use `on duplicate update` then you can update the balance if the user already has a balance/account.

Comment: I Am looking into this right now :) but it cant update because its not set as anything? by that i mean there is no value, because its not inserted into the database, the base value is 0.00 but if they add something to it it updates say $1, how would it show that how would it get the value of a html element?

Comment: Ah nevermind i see, so when they add money it updates to that varible of money?

Comment: Yes, it will `insert` or `update`.

Comment: Thanks for this documentation it helps alot, one question how would i get a html element to be the integer in a database say balance?

Answer (score 0):

Take from PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by binding PHP variables */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$sth->bindParam(':colour', $colour, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
$sth->execute();
?>
```

so your code will be:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users (64ID, BALANCE, AMOUNTBET) VALUES (:_64id, :balance, :amountbet)");

$_64id = $steamprofile['steamid'];
$balance = "";
$amountbet = "";

$stmt->bind_param(:_64id, $_64id);
$stmt->bind_param(:balance, $balance);
$stmt->bind_param(:amountbet, $amountbet);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Should i make a brand new question for this or could i ask you, how would i make it so if the 64id = to the one when you login? would i do select 1 from csgodb where 64ID = ? (64ID)? i've only done that in python so how would i do it in php, the documentation dosen't help me.